# Android: Launch Shortcut picker

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

I have looked everywhere for something related to this. I want to launch a shortcut, based on the shortcuts installed on a device.

A simple way of putting this is my user selects one of his shortcuts through my application. When the user initiates the shortcut through my app, it will perform the exact same thing as if he/she is on the home screen and selects the shortcut.

I can do this individually with the system shortcuts, but I want to have more flexibility for other shortcuts installed on the device.

So basically, I need to figure out how to bring up the shortcut picker (the same list that appears by long pressing a home screen and selecting shortcuts), get the intent to launch that shortcut and store that within my application data for use later. I don't want to actually initiate the shortcut when the user selects it, I just want to remember it for later.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same. No clue yet...

Comment: @SemperGumbee Hey! i'm trying to do pretty much the same thing, did you find a answer anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT